# Make Dictionary From Repeating Set of Data in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

Given an input like this:

```
1 2
2 3
2 5
5 1
3 4
4 5
4 6
```

I am trying to make it into a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {
    1: [2, 5],
    2: [1, 3, 5],
    3: [2, 4],
    4: [3, 5, 6],
    5: [1, 2, 4],
    6: [2, 4],
}
```

Think of it as vertices and its corresponding neighbors. So vertex 1 has two distinct neighbors: 2 and 5... etc

I thought it would be ideal to make data into a 2d array and traverse the list and add new values to the dictionary

```
inp = []
for i in range(7):
    v1, v2 = map(int, input().split())
    inp.append([v1, v2])
```

returns:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 5], [5, 1], [3, 4], [4, 5], [4, 6]]
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here

Comment: The input is a file?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DaniMesejo please see new edit

Comment: You need a `collections.defaultdict(list)`. There is an exact analogue of your problem in the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(set)
for line in range(7):
    source, target = map(int, input().strip().split())
    result[source].add(target)
    result[target].add(source)

result = {k: list(v) for k, v in result.items()}
print(result)
```

As an alternative you could use a dict with [setdefault](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault):

```
result = {}
for line in range(7):
    source, target = map(int, input().strip().split())
    result.setdefault(source, set()).add(target)
    result.setdefault(source, set()).add(source)

result = {k: list(v) for k, v in result.items()}
print(result)
```

**Output** *(for the given input)*

```
{1: [2, 5], 2: [1, 3, 5], 3: [2, 4], 5: [1, 2, 4], 4: [3, 5, 6], 6: [4]}
```

Comment: One minor issue with `setdefault` is that you repeatedly create an empty set, whether you need it or not. The `defaultdict` instance will only call `set` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were thinking something like this?

```
dict = {'1': [], '2': [], '3': [], '4': [], '5': [], '6': []}
with open("input.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        u, v = line.split()
        dict[u].append(v)
        dict[v].append(u)


print(dict)
```

output was slightly different from yours:

```
{'1': ['2', '5'], '2': ['1', '3', '5'], '3': ['2', '4'], '4': ['3', '5', '6'], '5': ['2', '1', '4'], '6': ['4']}
```

Mine won't prevent repetitions though

Comment: To make the numbers ints you could use the same method as OP's using: `u, v = map(int, line.split())`. And the problem with your solution is that it claims to know all nodes present in advance. What if the file has a node `7`? Your code will crash...

Comment: I would have to find a way to initialize dict with the number of lines in the file. Not sure how. Tried to find the right constructor for this but haven't yet.

Comment: Look at the other answer to this question... It has some helpful links